# Passing Variable to Forloop in Liquid/Jekyll

Tags: for-loop, variables, jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to create an html fragment in liquid/jekyll for the purposes of re-use across different areas. I'm able to pass data successfully from the parent html into the child fragment, but unable to figure out how to access passed variables within a forloop in the child.

parent.html:

```html
  {% assign section = 'work' %}
  {% include child.html %}
```

child.html (fragment):

```html
    {{ section }} <!-- prints 'work' as expected -->
    {% for scene in site.data.case-studies.[page.title].{{ section }}-scenes %} 

      <!-- this is not executed --> 
      <!-- note: also tried using bracket notation to access "section" in the above loop --> 

      {% for image in scene.TopLeft %}
        <img id="top-left-{{ section }}" src="img/{{ section }}/top-left.svg" />   
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The forloop isn't executed because I'm not able to pass `section = 'work'` to create a forloop such as: `{% for scene in site.data.case-studies.[page.title].work-scenes %}`.

How can I pass the section variable into the forloop in liquid/jekyll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

```
{% assign section = 'work-scenes' %}
```

and then use

```
{% for scene in for scene in site.data.case-studies[page.title][section] %}
```

or, if you must not alter the `scene` variable, create a new variable instead

```
{% assign sectionscenes = section | append: "-scenes" %}
```

and then use

```
{% for scene in for scene in site.data.case-studies[page.title][sectionscenes] %}
```

Ie, create a variable that holds the *complete* name of your property in the data. This also works across different files, because an `{% include %}` more or less just replaces the statement with the content of the file.